# Is there any good idea for App Store screenshot automation?

Tags: flutter, automation, fastlane, figma

I was wondering how to create the necessary store screenshots for multilingualization.

I was wondering how to make a screenshot of the store needed for multilingualization.

I found that
On the development side, there is a way to take automatic screenshots like fastlane, but it seems to show only a consistent screen, and there seems to be a limit to showing language translation problems and fancy screenshots.

If it's difficult to do it in development, I think you can refer to localization support figma plugins on the design side, but maybe I can ask how other people do it?!

A way for App Store screenshot automation